# Javascript - Multiple Event Listeners with One Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, event-handling

Currently I am dynamically generating buttons with event listeners from a database and using the information from these buttons to fill in a form when the button is clicked on. The problem that I am having is that if I click on more than one button before I hit submit, then it will process the action for all the buttons that were  previously clicked. Right now I would only like it to submit the data from the last button that I clicked. Is there a way to only have the information from the last button that I clicked submitted? I am pretty new to Javascript, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question

Here is the jsfiddle to an example of what I am trying to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/jviro/drmm5b48/2/

```
//edit item function
var buttons = [5,10,20];
var total;
var divButtons = document.getElementById("buttons");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    var aButton = document.createElement("a");
    aButton.setAttribute("href", "#");
    aButton.setAttribute("id", buttons[i]);
    aButton.setAttribute("class", "amountButtons");
    aButton.addEventListener("click", showNumber);
    var text = document.createTextNode(buttons[i]);
    aButton.appendChild(text);
    divButtons.appendChild(aButton);
}

function showNumber() {

    var clickedID = parseInt(this.id);
    var amount = document.getElementById("purchase_amount");
    amount.value = clickedID;

    //button interaction
    $( "#purchasesButton" ).click(function() {
        if(total == null){
            total = clickedID;
        }
        else{
            total = total + clickedID;
        }
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
        document.getElementById("purchases").reset();
    });
}
```

Comment: By "last button" you mean last time save button was clicked? So if you press 5 and then 10 and then save it sends 15? and then 5 and 20 it sends 25?

Comment: Why are you using `addEventListener` when you use jQuery?

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind one event handler inside another event handler function. Every time you call `showNumber`, you're adding another `click` handler to `purchasesButton`.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by "last button" was the last number that I selected. When I press 5 and then 10, and then hit the submit button, it submits both 5 and 10. I would like it to only submit the last number selected(the 10 in this example) @Samurai. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I am pretty new to both javascript and jQuery(and programming for that matter), so I am just using whichever method I find first on w3schools or a forum. I didn't realize it was a bad idea to to have event handler inside of a handler. That could be part of the problem I am having in the actual app that I am making. What do you think would be a better way to generate buttons with event handlers and only use one form to gather data? @Barmar

Comment: I posted an answer showing how I recommend doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted, you aren't submitting data anywhere, you are just adding amounts together than displaying it on the page when the `save` button is clicked.

If you want the amounts to not add together, but just display the last number clicked, then remove the addition from the code.

Instead of

```
  if(total == null){
      total = clickedID;
  }
  else{
      total = total + clickedID;
  }
```

just use

```
  total = clickedID;
```

See:

https://jsfiddle.net/jviro/drmm5b48/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the last value selected, you can put it in a global variable.

```js
//edit item function
var buttons = [5, 10, 20];
var total = null;
var divButtons = document.getElementById("buttons");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var aButton = document.createElement("a");
    aButton.setAttribute("href", "#");
    aButton.setAttribute("id", buttons[i]);
    aButton.setAttribute("class", "amountButtons");
    var text = document.createTextNode(buttons[i]);
    aButton.appendChild(text);
    divButtons.appendChild(aButton);
}

// Use jQuery to add an event binding to all the buttons at once.
$(".amountButtons").click(showNumber);

function showNumber() {
    var clickedID = parseInt(this.id);
    var amount = document.getElementById("purchase_amount");
    amount.value = clickedID;
    total = clickedID;
}

$("#purchasesButton").click(function () {
    if (total == null) {
        alert("No amount selected");
        return;
    }
    $("#total").text("Total: " + total);
    $("#purchases").reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons"></div>
<div>
    <form id="purchases">
        <p>how much is it?</p>
        <input type="number" name="purchase_amount" id="purchase_amount" value="">
    </form>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="purchasesButton" />

<h2 id="total">Total: </h2>
```